# How can I check if a variable exists in Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I'm using Smarty template engine.

I'm doing a simple login page. I set a variabile named **error** with a message if there are some problems, but IF NOT I get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: error
```

How could I check if this variable exists?

I only do:

```
{if $error}<h1>{$error}</h1>{/if}
```

thanks

Comment: The answers below do not take into account that a variable can be set to `null`. $error may exist and be null, in which case isset($error) returns false.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

isset() - [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=41474) - [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
isset($error)
```

Answer (score 68):

There you go!

```
{if isset($error)}
    {* TODO something *}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
{if $error|default}<h1>{$error}</h1>{/if}
```

"*|default*" modifier check if variable exist and accept one param (default: empty string)

Answer (score -3):

This is short :)
 No warnings or errors.

```
{if $error}
```

Comment: As you could see in the question this produces a notice. I assume you have the errorlevel high enough that you don't see notices.

Comment: In PHP 8.1, the notice has become a warning: `PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "value" on null in [template]`. The compiled code would here be `<?php if ($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['error']->value) {?>`, but tpl_vars['error'] wouldn't exist.